# Where is my Windows folder in Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Ubuntu in my windows 10. I would like to share the data between my windows and Linux.

But I can't able to find the Linux folders from the windows nor the windows folders from Linux. Is there a way to access from one another? I installed Ubuntu from windows store.

Comment: How did you install it? Via Windows Store? WSL information can be found at https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-nt-subsystem-and-vice

Comment: @LexLi you can install wsl from Microsoft store too.

Comment: Be **Very Very Aware**, [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : Thanks for this awareness. So I will always access the windows files from Linux. and NEVER access Linux files from windows.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Could you kindly migrate my question to the better place in stead of down voting.. Thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

windows drive will be mounted on /mnt location in your WSL

accessing C drive in bash on windows

```
ls -l /mnt/c
```

Comment: The Ubuntu root is mounted as /, in Explorer, from location: C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_<buildstamp>\LocalState\rootfs, or /mnt/c/Users etc. from bash prompt. Due to this mount being case sensitive it is generally ok to copy files into the tree, but ymmv copying to other parts of file system from there. Copies like this may need chown and chmod applied too as separate steps.

Answer (score 2):

First, a matter of terminology: folders are only a GUI artifact. What Linux [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) deal with are [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)).

> I just installed Ubuntu in my windows 10.

This is unclear. [Operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (both Ubuntu & Windows) are running -by definition- above the [bare metal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bare_machine) (perhaps a VM emulating the bare metal) and are providing services and abstractions to applications. So you cannot run one OS above another (except in a VM or some compatibility layer). I understand that you have installed both Ubuntu and Windows on your computer, in different disk partitions, and that you choose which OS you are using at boot time (perhaps thru some [grub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB) menu).

Then, learn more about [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (but don't confuse WSL with Ubuntu). It could be relevant (but you might not have it, if your Windows is not recent or if you have not installed it). If you use WSL you are *not* running Ubuntu (e.g. because you are not using a [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel)), even if you could run most Ubuntu [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) with WSL (but probably not all of them; it is rumored that [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.Org_Server) or [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) applications cannot run under WSL).

At last, what you probably want is to share some [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) file system and access it from Windows. Then you simply need some ext4 driver for Windows, such as [ext2fs](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) (but I guess that WSL provide something close).

A web search with `ext4 on windows` gives a lot of relevant answers, notably [this](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) one.

If your Linux file system is not ext4 (check with the [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) command as `mount -l`), adapt my answer to your file system type.

> I would like to share the data between my windows and Linux.

A reasonable approach would be to have a dedicated disk partition for that and use some file system (probably ext4, or maybe NTFS or VFAT) on it which can be read on both Windows and Linux. You certainly want to avoid messing your Linux system files from Windows (even by mistake).

If you want to read some Windows partition from Ubuntu (not WSL!) you should consider [mounting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(Unix)) it (e.g. as NTFS) on Linux. You still should avoid messing Windows system files from Linux.